# data using a method is not being saved in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I wanted to use @reload.status = boolean (true or false) but i could not get the boolean to be save into the database.

Also, i had been doing this all the time but it doesn't work now.

```
  def return
   ret = ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::Ipay88::Notification.new(request.raw_post)
   if ret.success?
     @reload = Reload.find(ret.item_id)
     @reload.status = true
     @reload.save
     redirect_to new_reload_path, notice: "Success"
   else
     @reload = Reload.find(ret.item_id)
     @reload.status = false
     redirect_to new_reload_path, notice: 'Reload unsuccessful'
   end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add @reload.save for the 'false' statement. (just like you see in "ret.success?" method call)